# Coldfusion - How to parse and segment out data from an email file

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am trying to parse email files that will be coming periodically for data that is contained within. We plan to setup cfmail to get the email within the box within CF Admin to run every minute.

The data within the email consists of name, code name, address, description, etc. and will have consistent labels so we are thinking of performing a loop or find function for each field of data. Would that be a good start?

Here is an example of email data:

> INCIDENT # 12345
>
> LONG TERM SYS#   C12345
>
> REPORTED: 08:39:34 05/20/19  Nature: FD NEED Address: 12345 N TEST LN 
>   City: Testville
>
> Responding Units: T12
>
> Cross Streets:    Intersection of: N Test LN & W TEST LN
>
> Lat= 39.587453        Lon= -86.485021
>
> Comments: This is a test post. Please disregard

Here's a picture of what the data actually looks like:

[image]

So we would like to extract the following:

1. INCIDENT
2. LONG TERM SYS#
3. REPORTED
4. Nature
5. Address
6. City
7. Responding Units
8. Cross Streets
9. Comments

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for replying.... Yes will will always have the same structure....

Comment: So would you say perform FindNoCase(INCIDENT#)??? But then how would we tell it to get the following string up until the end of the data? Thank you so much for helping.....

Comment: I added a pic of exactly what the data looks like. In the actual email file it looks like items "nature" "Address" "City" etc. are on separate lines, but theres not hard breaks.

Comment: We're using CF10

Comment: Are the emails being sent using an html form to an action page over which you have control?  If so, the easiest way to do this is to process the form data when it is submitted.

Comment: Someone just posted a great solution that I built in and it worked beautifully. But since a few minutes ago it looks like it was deleted. Would certainly like to share as it was an extremely helpful FUNCTION and code. Plus certainly would like to thank the poster.......

Comment: Is this an email format that you control or can modify the source?

Comment: Not really.... but I am going to post the solution that worked great. I thank everyone for taking the time to help!!!

Comment: Careful with the removed solution. If it was deleted from an answer, the poster may have found an error.

Comment: If not "hard breaks" (do you mean ascii char 10), what are they? Which email format, text or html?

Comment: I would also reiterate my standard disclaimer that CF10 is _WAY_ past EOL and is very exploitable. Upgrading that server is a serious conversation I'd press with whoever is making those kinds of decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this but it was apparently deleted. Whoever it was I want to thank you VERY MUCH as it worked perfectly!!!!

Here is the function:

```
   <!---CREATE FUNCTION [tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1   
varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   as (Select 1 From (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))     
N(N)),
   cte2(N)   as (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By    
(Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A   
),
   cte3(N)   as (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t 
Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
   cte4(N,L) as (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-
 S.N,8000) From cte3 S)


 Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
  ,RetPos = N
  ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 

 From  ( Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) From cte4 ) A

 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
 )
```

And here is the CF code that worked:

```
 <cfquery name="body" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
                    Declare @S varchar(max) ='
                    INCIDENT  12345

                    LONG TERM SYS C12345

                    REPORTED: 08:39:34 05/20/19 Nature: FD NEED Address: 12345 N TEST   
  LN City: Testville

                    Responding Units: T12

                    Cross Streets: Intersection of: N Test LN & W TEST LN

                    Lat= 39.587453 Lon= -86.485021

                    Comments: This is a test post. Please disregard
                    '

                    Select Incident = ltrim(rtrim(B.RetVal))
                          ,LongTerm = ltrim(rtrim(C.RetVal))
                          ,Reported = ltrim(rtrim(D.RetVal))
                          ,Nature   = ltrim(rtrim(E.RetVal))
                          ,Address  = ltrim(rtrim(F.RetVal))
                          ,City     = ltrim(rtrim(G.RetVal))
                          ,RespUnit = ltrim(rtrim(H.RetVal))
                          ,CrossStr = ltrim(rtrim(I.RetVal))
                          ,Comments = ltrim(rtrim(J.RetVal))
                     From (values (replace(replace(@S,char(10),''),char(13),' ')) )A(S)
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'INCIDENT'       ,'LONG 
 TERM'  ) B
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'LONG TERM SYS'   
 ,'REPORTED'   ) C
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'REPORTED:'        ,'Nature'     
 ) D
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'Nature:'          
  ,'Address'    ) E
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'Address:'         ,'City'       
  ) F
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'City:'            
  ,'Responding ') G
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'Responding Units:','Cross'      
   ) H
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S,'Cross Streets:'   ,'Lat'       
  ) I
                     Outer Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](S+'|||','Comments:'  ,'|||'        
   ) J
                    </cfquery>
                    <cfoutput>
                    B. #body.Incident#<br>
                    C. #body.LongTerm#<br>
                    D. #body.Reported#<br>
```

Comment: This is pretty much almost a pure SQL solution, and would be better indicated as such for anyone who comes across this later. Plus, a lot of the code is testing code with a set example. If you are storing your extracted values into the database, then it would make sense to process this in SQL. But if not, there's no need for a trip to the database. SQL isn't all that great for parsing text.

Comment: Shawn, how would you suggest doing it is Coldfusion? Thanks

Comment: Are you inserting the parsed data back into the database? And do you have a redacted example of the full email file that you're parsing? Is this an HTML email or a plaintext? And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: *Is this an HTML email or a plaintext?* Frequently, both are available. Using the text version would is better for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tends to have limited string functions, so it isn't the best tool for parsing. If the email content is ***always*** in that exact format, you could use either plain string functions or regular expressions to parse it. However, the latter is more flexible.

I suspect the content actually does contain new lines, which would make for simpler parsing. However, if you prefer searching for content in between two labels, regular expressions would do the trick.

Build an array of the label names (only). Loop through the array, grabbing a pair of labels: "current" and "next". Use the two values in a regular expression to extract the text in between them:

```
label &"\s*[##:=](.*?)"& nextLabel

/* Explanation: */
label        - First label name (example: "Incident")
\s*          - Zero or more spaces 
[##:=]       - Any of these characters: pound sign, colon or equal sign 
(.*?)        - Group of zero or more characters (non-greedy) 
nextLabel    - Next label (example: "Long Term Sys")
```

Use [reFindNoCase()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/refindnocase.html) to get details about the position and length of matched text. Then use those values in conjunction with [mid()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/mid.html) to extract the text.

<sub>*Note, newer versions like ColdFusion 2016+ automagically extract the text under a key named `MATCH`*</sub>
[image: Example of reFindNoCase result in CF 2018]

The newer CF2016+ syntax is slicker, but something along these lines works under CF10:

```
emailBody = "INCIDENT # 12345 ... etc.... ";
labelArray = ["Incident", "Long Term Sys", "Reported", ..., "Comments" ];

for (pos = 1; pos <= arrayLen(labelArray); pos++) {

    // get current and next label
    hasNext   = pos < arrayLen(labelArray);
    currLabel = labelArray[ pos ];
    nextLabel = (hasNext ? labelArray[ pos+1 ] : "$");

    // extract label and value
    matches   = reFindNoCase( currLabel &"\s*[##:=](.*?)"& nextLabel, emailBody, 1, true);
    if (arrayLen(matches.len) >= 2) {
        results[ currLabel ] = mid( emailBody, matches.pos[2], matches.len[2]);
    }   
}

writeDump( results );
```

**Results:**

[image: Screenshot of parsed results]

Comment: Ageax, thank you very much for your response. I appreciate it very much. I have been trying to put that into CF code (.cfm) and keep getting errors. Would you be able to tell me how to put if into cfm code? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Scott - Just wrap the code block in `<cfscript> ...</cfscript>`. As long as you've populated the label array and `emailBody` (with the content), it should work out of the box.  Granted you could also convert it to CFML, but that's less readable IMO.

Comment: https://trycf.com/gist/d2937e3ae573678ab83d56e592c61741/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Ageax, This has worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much for the help. I am trying one more step where I dynamically populate the array and then I want to display the output of the array. So I tried adding the following code:

Comment: <cfoutput>
                        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(labelArray)#" index="pos">
                        #labelArray[pos]#:
                        <cfset temp_var2 = #replace(labelArray[pos], " ", "+", "All")#>
      <cfset temp_var = 'results.#temp_var2#'>
                        #Evaluate(temp_var)#
                        #Evaluate("results.#temp_var2#")#
                        <br>
                        </cfloop>
      
      </cfoutput>

Comment: But the big problem I'm getting when it gets to an array item that has spaces, it breaks. So for example when I get to Long Term Sys, it will give me an error noting that "Long" is not a var in Results. As you can see I tried replacing the spaces with "+" and using Evaluate. No luck. Any ideas? Thank you once again for all your help!!!

Comment: Well I'm trying to apply this code so it can work for a number of sets of labels (Incident, Long Term Sys, Comments, etc) because it will change. Therefore I'd like to place it into a database field so it can easily be changed. So as I loop through the array, I need to use the actual label (Long Term Sys) but also the value of that label (C12345). But it breaks when I loop through and get to a label that has spaces (Long Term Sys) but works for one word items like "Reported"

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you just want to display the results dynamically, use structure notation. *After* populating the structure, loop through the label array and use the current element to display the label name and value . i.e. `<cfloop array="#labelArray#" index="label"> #label# = #result[ label ]#</cfloop>`

Comment: Tried that but keep getting "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members. " Thanks

Comment: My bad. The code needs to use the correct structure name, i.e. `results` (plural) not `result` (singular).

Comment: Ageax, I don't mean to take up all your time... but I am trying to make the vars dynamic by setting the following in the db: <cfset  labelArray = [#get_account.CAD_vars#]> which is "INCIDENT,LONG TERM CAD,REPORTED,Nature,Address,City,Responding Units,Cross Streets,Lat,Lon,Comments" in the db. But when I run it I get this error: The element at position 2 cannot be found. Any idea? I think its got to with the following correct: matches   = reFindNoCase( currLabel &"\s*[##:=](.*?)"& nextLabel, emailBody, 1, true);

Comment: Actually I ended up using: <cfset labelArray = listToArray (get_account.CAD_vars, ",",false,true)> and it worked. Thanks again Ageax, I truly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Welcome. Just keep in mind order is important.  The code searches for *pairs* of labels. Storing them in a db is fine, but ... if the sql query retrieves the labels out of order, obviously the code will break.

Comment: @SOS, if the same emailtemplate contains pairs of block such as first block contains order details with the labels and values orderid:1, ordername:'xxx', orderdate:'yyy' again we will have other orderdetails in the same tempate. So how can we parse the entire email to get 2 different order blocks. The code you mentioned is to retrieve lable like orderid, ordername from overall email. But the requirement I am asking is before that I need to get number of blocks. I am trying now. But if you have any idea please share me that would be more and more helpfule to me..

Comment: got it with "all" value in refindnocase function. Thank you SOS.