# FindNoCase not working for multiple word searches

Tags: coldfusion

I have a list of keywords that I am looking for their position in a text file. All is good until I have a keyword that has multiple words.

So for example I have a string that I am searching:

> Hello I am a string of wonderful words that will blow your mind time again. Here are some values:
>
> Value 1: this is the value for one
>   Value 2: this is the value for two
>   Value 3: this is the value for three

So I have a list of keywords: `list = "wonderful words, value 1, value 2, value 3"`

So I need to loop through the list and find the word/phrase, then get it's position so I can perform a mid function to get the data.

The problem is when a keyword is a collection of words it is ignored.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
 <cfset stringToSearch = "INCIDENT # 12345

 LONG TERM SYS#   C12345
 REPORTED: 15:08:34 05/21/19
  Nature: MEDICAL
 Address: 34234 W Test ST; 312S
 City: Testville

 Responding Units: F32423

 Cross Streets:
 Between: Test ST & N Tester ST

 Lat= 39.429019        Lon= -86.432111

 Comments: This is a comment"> 

 <cfset list_to_search = 'INCIDENT:,LONG TERM  SYS:,REPORTED:,Nature:,Address:,City:,Responding Units:,Cross Streets:,Lat=,Lon=,Comments'>

 <cfoutput>

 <cfset x = '1'>
 <cfset last_keyword = "">
 <cfloop list="#list_to_search#" index="keyword" delimiters=",">
     <cfif #x# neq '1'>
     #x#. #last_keyword# - #keyword# <br><br>
     1st: #REFind(last_keyword,stringToSearch)#<br>
     2nd: #REFind(keyword,stringToSearch)#<br>
     #x#. #last_keyword#: #Mid(stringToSearch,       
     FindNoCase(last_keyword,stringToSearch)+len(last_keyword),   
     FindNoCase(keyword,stringToSearch)-  
     FindNoCase(last_keyword,stringToSearch))#<br><br>
    </cfif>
    <cfset last_keyword = #keyword#>
    <cfset #x# = #x# + 1>
</cfloop>
```

I'm trying to get the starting position at the end of a keyword all the way to the beginning of the next keyword to get the data in between. Like I said all is good until multiple word keyword.

Comment: I created a gist to show a different perspective on dealing with this. Basically break that string into smaller chunks and then use builtin functions to parse them. I didn't post it as an answer because it is VERY specific to the data you gave here. I don't really like it but maybe it will help get you going. [Play with the gist here](https://www.trycf.com/gist/0042f585500b6ee55fd031a0c8f8e8bc/acf?theme=monokai)

Comment: Please also label the version of CF you are using.

Comment: Also, since this seems to be related to your previous question about parsing an email, it might be helpful to include those details or link that question, too.

Comment: If you need to read/extract stuff, [use reMatchNoCase](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/rematchnocase.html) to match your keyword patterns. It's easier to read and easier to maintain than substringing your way through it.

Comment: *"all is good until multiple word keyword"* FindNoCase() doesn't care whether you're matching multiple words, only that the substrings match what's in the search string EXACTLY.  In your example above, they're different. For example the keywords contain `INCIDENT:` (colon, no space) but stringToSearch contains `INCIDENT #` (space, pound sign). Keywords contain `LONG TERM  SYS:` (double space, colon) but stringToSearch contains `LONG TERM SYS#` (single spaces, pound sign), etc...

Comment: Since this seems to be the same problem that was solved [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277400/coldfusion-how-to-parse-and-segment-out-data-from-an-email-file), this thread is basically a duplicate. Since it has no answers, best to just delete it. If the issue on the other thread is resolved, that thread should be closed out.